# Polymode installation on Windows machine

Tags: ess, polymode

[Polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode#basic-usage) is very promising to handle the integration of R chunks using different modes.
I went through the documentation and it works well when I am inside `.Rmd` file but not inside `.Rnw`. In the `.Rnw` I found the `Noweb` mode activated without polymode `PM-rmd`. So there must be something wrong with my installation on Windows machine.

**installation**
I installed `rmarkdown-mode` from MELPA, BTW this was not shown clearly in the documentation of polymode, I wish there was a requirement section in it.

I was confused about that part of installation:

```
(setq load-path
      (append '("path/to/polymode/"  "path/to/polymode/modes")
              load-path))
```

Because in Windows, `polymode` resides in `c:/emacs/.emacs.d/elpa/polymode-20150105.931/` but I don't see the `\modes` folder in there! So is the above code needed if I had used `install-packages` from MELPA?

I installed the `polymode` package from MELPA. `M-x list packages`.

I have `pandoc` installed and checked in the PATH variables by `M-x getenv RET PATH RET`; pandoc was there.

**relevant `.init.el` code**

```
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
;; Markdown
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))

;;; R related modes
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
(setq ess-swv-processing-command "%s(%s)") % this to get rid of .ess_weave() function not found error
```

**MWE of .Rnw file**

```
\documentclass[a4]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
  Here is a code chunk.
<<demo, fig.height=4,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
summary(cars)
qplot(speed,dist,data=cars) +
  geom_smooth()
@
You can also write inline expressioins, e.g. $\pi=\Sexpr{pi}$.
\end{document}
```

**Notes**

- Windows 7 32 bit
- Polymode updated from MELPA

**Update**
I used this code right after ESS code in the `init.el` and it worked well:

```
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
```

I realized that for MELPA installation these lines of code in the documentation are irrelevant:

```
(setq load-path
      (append '("path/to/polymode/"  "path/to/polymode/modes")
              load-path))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `poly-noweb+r-mode` to `auto-mode-alist` for `Rnw` files. You also need to watch for conflicts with ESS. ESS adds its own mode to `auto-mode-alist` for Rnw files, so you have to wait until *after* this happens to make sure you over-ride the ESS settings. This is what I have in my .emacs:

```
(require 'polymode)
(require 'poly-R)
(eval-after-load 'ess-site 
  '(progn 
     (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[rR]md" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
     (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[rR]nw" . poly-noweb+r-mode)))
```

Comment: is it necessary to put this code after ESS code in the `init.el` file or doesn't matter?

Comment: It shouldn't matter - (eval-after-load ...) should hold off on cleaning up the ess stuff until after it has loaded. Just to be safe, I'll edit it to put the next line into the same form.

Comment: @doctorate, @Tyler You need not put all the `(requre ..)`s, `poly-R` should be enough. Also deleting Rnw-mode is not necessary, the first assignment in `auto-mode-alist` takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks @VitoshKa ! And thanks for polymode, it's fantastic

Comment: I confirm that there is no need to `require (polymode)`. I just put the code after the ESS code and it worked well (as in the update).