# Polymode appears in minibuffer but does not weave into a file on Windows, why?

Tags: latex, ess, polymode

This is a follow-up post to [Polymode installation on Windows machine](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/8223/2443). Accordingly I installed polymode using this code in the `init.el` file after ESS code:

```
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
```

This seems to work as `polymode` (PM-Rnw) does appear in the minibuffer:

[image]

Now I want to weave this file using `M-n w` and `knitr` option, it prompts me then whether this is the master file:

[image]

When I hit `RET` to accept the default (same file is master file), I get this message:

[image]

This indicates that a `mwe_demo[weaved].tex` buffer has already been created and transferred to a project cache in projectile. But this buffer is empty and no such file was ever found in that path. So what am I missing here?

**Update**
the following message appears in the `*polymode weave*` buffer:

```
weaving latex with command:
     Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('mwe_demo.Rnw', output='mwe_demo[weaved].tex')"
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So it seems that `knitr` could not be loaded because of no recognized `Rscript.exe` shell command. This means that it won't use the `Rterm.exe` that I have this line of ESS installation in `init.el`:

```
(setq-default inferior-R-program-name "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/bin/i386/Rterm.exe")
```

but how to make `Rscript` recognized which I have it on this path `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/bin/Rscript.exe`? I hope that was more explained in the documentation.

I ended up adding the above path to PATH variables `Win + break`. It worked now and weaved into `.tex` file. Now when I press `M-x e/E` I get two candidates `pdflatex|latexmk` how to extend that to include `xelatex`, which is more useful in my case?

**Updated Question**

How to make polymode opt for `xelatex`?

A similar case with `Noweb` mode could be solved by `M-x customize-group` as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28515366/1288722

**Note**

- The same file could be weaved successfully using the `Noweb` mode in ESS using `knitr`
- Pandoc is already installed and in the PATH variable `M-x getenv RET PATH RET`
- Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 3):

After some trials on Windows machine, I found this workflow works very well:

**Installation for Windows users**

*Step 1*
Put this in your `init.el` or `.emacs.el` file - after ESS code:

```
(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
;;; MARKDOWN
; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))

;;; R modes
; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Snw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
```

*Step 2*
Put `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/bin` into PATH variable of your Windows; `Win + break` shortcut is useful. This step to make sure that `Rscript.exe` will be accessible by shell command of polymode to load `knitr` package.

*Step 3*
Once you have polymode file say `.Rnw` or alike ready and you have already fired up your ESS R session, you can issue `M-x w` to weave it (I use Knitr).

*Step 4*
Instead of issuing `M-x e` or `M-x E` directly from `.Rnw` file (which has only latexmk | pdfaltex options), I tend to open the newly generated weaved `.tex` file (if not already opened for you in other window) and hit the usual `C-c C-c` command to compile it using my favorite default engine `xetex`, if you don't have it as default, this line in your `init.el` will let you do so:

```
(setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
```